# App scaling issues in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I'm a complete newbie at Visual Studio but I am wanting to create a decently simple app for my own use on a desktop. I am decently adept at python and VBA so I do have some coding experience. While adapting to the new languages is confusing, I think I can manage and that's not the purpose of this post. I have looked and I can't seem to get a clear answer to this problem.

Essentially, I would like to know how to make what I see in the Design view be exactly what I see when I run the app using the Local Machine option. When the project was created I chose C#>Windows>Windows 8>Windows and then chose the blank app for windows 8.1 as that's what I'm running currently. My problem is that my monitor is 1920x1080. When I design something on MainPage.xaml using the xaml code and the design viewport, I figured out how to make things look nice. However, when I click to run the app using the Local Machine option at the top of the program things get weird.

The app opens just fine; the backgrounds and individual elements are fine. However the alignment of everything is off. I can make a few tweaks to get things to look better but I always have the same issue that whatever is in the design view does not go exactly when the app is launched.

I've narrowed down the problem to the Device menu where under the Display dropdown I can choose a lot of resolutions which change the design view. However the only 1920x1080 resolution is at 140% scaling which doesn't help. Is there any way that I can get this to be 100% scaling instead or another way that I haven't figured out?

This image is what I'm talking about:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/y0vIqRX.png]

Note how the rectangle on the right move drastically when the app is run. All individual components are the right amount of pixels and such, but the background grid messes things up when it tries to scale. Pretty much I want what is in the design view is exactly represented when I go to launch it.

Thanks for all the help you can give. This editor is really confusing.

Comment: Well no. Actually XAML and the WPF rendering engine is doing a good job. You told your grid some specific width and height properties(Column and Row-Definitions) and it sticks to them. The question is: What do you want to achieve? And it might be very helpful if you post the corresponding XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening, is that the `*` character that you have following all of your column widths stands for weighted average (not width in pixels!!!). Since the center column has the greatest weight, the effects are most apparent there. If you don't want to re-visit your layout approach, you can do the following: Remove the `*` from your grid column widths, and wrap your entire grid with a `Viewbox` and hard-code the width of the grid:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid x:Name="backGrid" Width="364">
    ....
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

What a viewbox does, is give the client control (the grid) infinite space, and then checks how much space it's used (364 in my example). It will then scale up the grid to fit the available space (while maintaining aspect ratio).

All this said, it should still be noted that this is a discouraged way to do your layout. Perhaps use a Canvas or DockPanel to do your layout instead of a grid. Or even you could just make sure that whatever control is in the center column is set to HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" so that it will fill the available space in the center column.

If you want some tips getting started with designing WPF layouts, let me know in the comments and I can send my skype name or something.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. I actually was able to figure it out. I guess I should have deleted the question or marked it solved... So I guess you can get the solved tag, enjoy!